# Optimal way to link cache folders into different location

Tags: linux, ssd, symbolic-link, cache, fstab

I use Arch Linux and I have spare m.2 SSD which I use for SWAP, but I have huge space left which is unused, so I would like to use it for cache / temp files too (so I can save some writes on my systems SSD).

I created entry in fstab file for that partition with unused space like:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/5f0ddbbd-9b8e-4499-8ccd-8e6993eb6c80 /mnt/5f0ddbbd-9b8e-4499-8ccd-8e6993eb6c80 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

then I created some "folder structure" of cache / temp folders in that partition, like:

```
-/home/username/.cache
-/var/
  -/cache/
  -/temp/
-/tmp/
```

Now I wonder what is the best way to map real system folders on system SSD to these folders on cache SSD, I was thinking about softlink like "ln -s", or map every folder like new entry in fstab file? I don't know what is recommended.

Second question is there any failsafe mechanism? I mean if my cache SSD corrupts, or I will need to boot up PC without that cache SSD? Because I found out that if cache folder is not accessible many things doesn't work, like terminal (so I had to go to the TTY). So by failsafe mechanism Im thinking something like that if there is not that cache SSD it will create cache / temp folders as they should be, and if there is, it should read / write to that cache SSD.

Comment: One question per post please. Also, asking about "optimal" methods usually gives your question the tone of asking for opinions. We want a working method. If your method works, then it is correct. Please edit your post to present a single question, and consider asking a more concrete and empirical question rather than "is there a better way to do this".

Comment: @music2myear I have no working solution yet, Im asking what is better in my scenario if symlink, fstab or something else which I dont know yet.